# How do I create a plot like this grid in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graphics

I have data like this

```
-1 -1 -1 1 0 0 1 1 -1 0 1 -1 0 1
```

where each element of the vector is one of a several states. In this case (which is arbitrary and obviously only an example), are `-1 0 1`. I'm trying to make a plot like this grid:

[image: example mock up]

The closest I was able to get was with a combination of `spy` and various tweaks:

```
%% ARBITRARY example data
states = [-1 0 1];
data = [-1 -1 -1 1 0 0 1 1 -1 0 1 -1 0 1];

%% Approximate plot using sparse matrix and spy
T = size(data, 2);
num_states = size(states, 2);
g = zeros(num_states, T);
for idx = 1:T
    jdx = find(data(idx) == states, 1, 'first');
    g(jdx, idx) = 1;
end
g = sparse(g);

%% Tweak plot
obj = figure();
obj.Color = 'white';
spy(g, 30)

s = obj.Children(1);
s.XLim = [1 T];
s.YLim = [1 num_states];
s.XLabel.String = '';
s.XGrid = 'on';

s.YTick = 1:num_states;
s.YTickLabel = num2cell(states);
s.GridLineStyle = '-';
s.YGrid = 'on';
```

However, this is far from ideal, since a) it's not actually a shaded grid, and b) the ticks on the y-axis are in descending order, starting from the bottom, because this is how `spy` functions, among other problems. How do I make a plot like this? I'm using MATLAB 2015b on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to play around with colours and grids, but this should be sufficient to get started:

```
data = [-1 -1 -1 1 0 0 1 1 -1 0 1 -1 0 1];
states = flipud(unique(data)');
im = bsxfun(@eq,data,states);

image(im);
colormap([1 1 1;0 0 0]);
axis equal;
axis tight;
set(gca,'XTick',1:length(data));
grid minor
set(gca,'YTickLabel',states);
```

The above results in

[image]

Comment: Great, this is quite helpful. I'll probably use `grid('on')` instead of `grid('minor')`, and I try to use the new graphics syntax (new in 2014b) wherever possible, but this is a great start to what I'm looking for. I didn't think to use `image` for this.